# PathTooLongException while creating new ApiController in asp.net-core mvc application

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a ASP.NET MVC project using ASP.NET web application Full framework template with .NET 4.6.1

I tried creating Api Controller using scaffolding item with Entity Framework. During creation it fails with an error message -

> "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.PathTooLongException." while executing
>   codegenerator.exe.

[image]

My project is like this-

> D:\Perforce\XYZ\ABC\POC\ABC_PROEJCT\src\ABC_PROEJCT\Controllers

This is how my **project.json** looks like-

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Glimpse": "2.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**My environment is-**

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

.NET framework 4.6.1

.NET core SDK 1.0 with preview 2 tooling set

Windows 7 64 bit OS

Could you please provide some inputs how to resolve this issue?

**Update on 20th September**

I see on **Output** tab in VS2015, following command getting executed while creating API Controller using scaffolding :

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe aspnet-codegenerator --project "D:\Perforce\###\#######\POC\################\src\################" controller --force --controllerName UserTypesTestController --model ################.Models.UserTypes --dataContext ################.Models.#####UserContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --controllerNamespace ################.Controllers --restWithNoViews.
```

The full path along with controller name does not exceed 260 characters.

Comment: please provide parameters, that are used for code generation

Comment: I didn't run it from CLI. I used Visual Studio, right clicked on controller->Add New Scaffold Item to add APIController.

Comment: @Set, I have added the code generation command with paramaters in my post.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows API (that is used), the maximum length for a path is `MAX_PATH`, which is defined as 260 characters.
During creation, the EF code generator tool tries to create file like

```
D:\Perforce\XYZ\ABC\POC\ABC_PROEJCT\src\ABC_PROEJCT\Controllers\Yourcontroller.cs
```

but looks like this path in the end takes more that 260 characters, and you see [System.IO.PathTooLongException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) error:

> The exception that is thrown when a path or file name is longer than the system-defined maximum length.

( actually the same message you have in your Error window)

To avoid this, you should decrease number of characters in your project path / controller name.

**Update, based on comments:**

the 260 character (MAXPATH) file name length limitation has been fixed in the System.IO APIs in 4.6.2 version, so upgrading project to use .NET framework 4.6.2 may be a solution.

Comment: From exception it is obvious that, we are exceeding 260 characters. But I have calculated the entire path length and It has **118 characters** to be precise.

Comment: @mvermef agh, they have fixed the 260 character (MAXPATH) file name length limitation in the System.IO APIs https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/ . I think you can post this as answer)

Answer (score 0):

4.6.2 solves this issue of maxpath exceedingg 260 characters https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, asp.net core 1.1, entity framework core 1.1.

I finally realized the problem was a `node_modules` folder in my project that had too many nested directories. If you look at the output tab you can see the exception is thrown during the Build step. Took me forever to realize it though. Although the project builds fine in Visual Studio, for some reason it throws an error there.

I created an issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/377

To resolve it, I deleted my `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install` again. This time I got a much flatter directory structure. I must have run it before upgrading npm.